# Authenticate domain-user credentials on unjoined virtual machine?

Tags: domain, authentication, virtual-machines, team-foundation-server, credentials

This question may sound silly, and perhaps a bit insane, but--is there any way to run a process on a machine not joined to a domain using credentials from a user in that domain?

In my case, I'm running virtual machines installed with release binaries from our build process, as well as Visual Studio. Visual Studio is there to debug our release binaries, however it's being executed with vm-local user credentials. This means that it can't authenticate to our TFS deployment when executing "tf.exe view" to utilize our Source Server for debugging.

Team Explorer manages to authenticate to TFS using a UI prompt, however I suspect that it's because we supply it with the TFS deployment's URI, and it's designed to display a prompt to facilitate workgroup scenarios; i.e. it's not like we're getting it for free.

My instincts tell me the only way to authenticate on this vm is to join it or somehow form a one-way trust or something, but is there an easier way? For automation we're going to want to script this eventually, but I'm first surveying the feasibility of the thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This question may sound silly, and perhaps a bit insane, but--is there any way to run a process on a machine not joined to a domain using credentials from a user in that domain?

The only way to do that is to join the workstation to the domain. This hooks it into the greater Active Directory trust framework. One-way trusts apply to domains, not workstations. Which is to say, a domained workstation trusts the domain for Auth, but the domain does not trust the Workstation for auth.